# Passing initialized dummy &str so it can be filled by a function

Tags: rust

My program initializes a variable "mag", and then passes it to a function that modifies it according to an int.

```
let n = some_number;
let m = "";
x = foo(n, m);

fn foo(n: u64, mut m: &str) -> &str {
    if n == 0 {
        m = "asdf";
    } else {
        m = "qwerty";
    return mag;
}
```

However I get a complier warning that mag is never read. I can't return a variable created inside a function, so I have to initialize mag outside. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass a reference around, you can pass ownership of a local variable outside of the function no problem. `String`s also dereference into a `&str` if you absolutely need one:

```
fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let n = 55;
    let x = foo(n);

    match &x[..] {
        "querty" => println!("Yep it was qwerty!"),
        _ => println!("Nope it wasn't qwerty :(")
    };

    Ok(())
}

fn foo(n: u64) -> String {
    if n == 0 {
        String::from("asdf")
    } else {
        String::from("querty")
    }
}
```

Prints "Yep it was qwerty!".

Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d7830c124171ab8a3c64f55a5c89590f

Edited to include matching as per your comment.

Comment: The reason I was returning a &str was that I then match on foo's result. It seemed tedious to write .to_string() after "asdf", etc. Should I just be writing .to_string() and matching on Strings instead of &str's then?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Essentially you can slice it an compare it to a `&str`.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are returning static strings, so you can do this:

```
fn foo(n: u64) -> &'static str {
    if n == 0 {
        "asdf"
    } else {
        "querty"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can do that, but you need to pass in a mutable reference, also you wouldn't be able to change the content of the `&str` (if that's what you're intending to do; `&str` are immutable in it self). You would just change `m` to point to another `&str`. This works seemlessly because `"asdf"` & `"qwerty"` are `'static` `str`s.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut m: &str = "";

    foo(42, &mut m);
    dbg!(m);

    foo(0, &mut m);
    dbg!(m);
}

fn foo(n: u64, m: &mut &str) {
    if n == 0 {
        *m = "asdf";
    } else {
        *m = "qwerty";
    }
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=de958d53198db1f7691ae953e1ffc63c